# Changing the I2C address on-the-fly of a linux device driver

Tags: linux-device-driver, i2c

I have two cameras attached to my linux system. The cameras are controlled via I2C. The device driver for a single camera is based on the `i2c-core` device driver. I want to switch between the two cameras. Therefore, I want to change the I2C address on the fly to control one or the other camera.

Is this reasonable? If yes, is there a function, which does that or is it necessary to detach and attach the client with `i2c_detach_client` and `i2c_attach_client`, respsectively?

Thanks for any advice, Stefan

Comment: Currently, I added a ioctl that overwrites the `addr` entry of `client` structure. Does not yet work. Most probably second camera is not yet initliazed correctly...

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly you should get a device for each camera under /dev/, why not open both devices instead of trying to do something that will require you to rewrite large parts of the driver?

I suggest you take a look at the documentation found here: http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/i2c (please note the different topics on the left hand side).

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Hm, the problem is that the two cameras share the data bus. Moreover, the I2C address is already hardwired in the driver. So, it is not possible to open two devices. Meanwhile, my hack works by changing the I2C address on the fly, but this not yet the "clean" solution I would like to have.

Answer (score 0):

The solution listed in your comment should work. I've written a generic I2C driver before with an ioctl interface that just sets the client->addr entry and it allowed me to test the bus.

Note that `i2c_detach_client` and `i2c_attach_client` functions have been removed in the more recent kernels.